# other-Language font name to system font name

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a font dialog in my project which will put the selected font name to a string variable, here is what I wrote:

```
fontselected = FontDialog1.Font.Name
```

However, if I select a Chinese font name such as 宋仿, the string in `fontselected` will also be the Chinese characters, is there any way to convert the Chinese font name to the system font name?In this case "SongFang"

Comment: That is not the system font name.  Afaik it is the FangSong font, simfang.ttf is the file on disk, usually located in c:\windows\fonts.  Mapping a face name back to the disk file is quite tricky, fonts generally are composed of multiple files.  Have a look at the registry with Regedit.exe, navigate to HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows NT/CurrentVersion.  The Fonts key maps face names to files.  You also ought to look at FontLink/SystemLink for a possible alias.  In general you should not be interested in this.

Comment: Thanks, i have changed my question on what i wrote wrong!